# PHP - Value for each

Tags: php, foreach

Hello I got a question: I want to make a table of these two arrays. In the first column I want the players name, second column the score and the third column the average of the score. I only get the players in the table and it is repeating itself. I dont know how to make it work. I know the value in the foreach is the players so I knew it would repeat itself but how can I fix this?

```
<?php
    $aScore = array (1 => 0, 2 => 20, 3 => 4, 4 => 23, 5 => 5, 6 => 4);

    $aPlayers = array (1 => 'Jansen', 2 => 'Boularus', 3 => 'Rintintin', 4 => 'Chavez', 5 => 'Zomers', 6 => 'Tahamata');

    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr><td>Player</td><td>Score</td><td>Average score</td></tr>';

    foreach($aPlayer as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td><td>'.$value.'</td></tr>';
    };

    echo '</table>';


    ?>
```

Comment: You have a key and an array. Use the key and the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
foreach($aPlayers as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<tr><td>'.$value.'</td><td>'. $aScore[$key] .'</td><td>'. $aAverageScore[$key] .'</td></tr>';
}
```

There is no `$aAverageScore` variable in your question but I assume that you will know what to put here instead.

However you should store your data in multidimentional associative array, like:

```
$players = array(
  array(
    'name'    => 'Jansen',
    'score'   => 0,
    'average' => 0
  ),
  array(
    'name'    => 'Boularus',
    'score'   => 20,
    'average' => 20
  ),
  // ...
);
```

And loop it with:

```
foreach ($players as $player) {
  echo '<tr><td>' . $player['name'] . '</td><td>' . $player['score'] . '</td><td>' . $player['average'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this one is working and it is the one I'm looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `for` loop instead of a `foreach`:

```
for ($k=1; $k<=count($aPlayer); $k++) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$aPlayer[$k].'</td><td>'.$aScore[$k].'</td><td></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: This one is working thanks for the answer but, it was not what I was searching for. Thanks anyway =)